# Selecting all data related to longest period between 2 dates

Tags: sql

So I'm trying to return all data from a table called missions for the mission with the longest period from its launch date to its recovery date. Here's what I have so far. I know something is off, I just don't know what.

```
SELECT* FROM missions
WHERE DATEDIFF(year,'launchdate', 'recoverydate') = (select MAX(DATEDIFF(year, 'launchdate','recoverydate'))
FROM missions)
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using SQL Server.  If so, you can use `TOP WITH TIES`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES m.*
FROM missions m
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(year, m.launchdate, m.recoverydate) DESC;
```

Note that you have misused single quotes in your query.  Otherwise, it should work.